# Are there any wars in the world not involving terrorism?

Tags: international-relations, armed-conflict

Most wars you hear of today are somehow linked to terrorism and state sponsored terrorism for the sake of some political agenda. Are there still any wars remaining between sovereign states?. If not, what was the last war of this kind?

Comment: Phillipines is threatening war with Canada over ... trash!   https://www.cnn.com/2019/04/24/asia/duterte-canada-trash-intl/index.html

Comment: @CrossRoads Do threats really count? North Korea has been threatening America, India has been threatening Pakistan.. It's not a war?

Comment: This is unanswerable without a specific definition of terrorism. Providing local insurgents with all kinds of support has been a standard strategy in war for quite some time now. Commando operations could be classified as terrorism as well, and often are by the target of the operation.

Comment: Do you mean terrorism as a non-denominal tactic, or terrorism as a weasel-word for jihad?

Comment: A war between militaries and not between insurgents and armies

Answer (score 4):

Even ignoring the terrorism question, this is hard to answer because official declarations of war don't happen so much recently.

[Russia vs Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Georgian_War) in 2008 was definitely a war by most standards, with regular army units fighting each other.

In 2016 there were [four days](https://web.archive.org/web/20160425045536/https://au.news.yahoo.com/world/a/31286381/fragile-truce-holds-in-karabakh-after-four-days-of-deadly-clashes/) of fighting on the Armenia Azerbaijan front. Officially this war never ended.

But then neither did the Korean war, and there were [sporadic incidents in that as well in recent times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_border_incidents_involving_North_and_South_Korea#2010s).

Comment: Neither has the second world war. There was no peace treaty.